# How to make mochajs display test details when running 'npm test'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Mocha.js does not display anything when running tests.

So I am using Typescript here. I have 2 folders: src and tests, and when I compile I get both of these folders of compiled code in the build folder.

I defined this script in my package.json: `"test": "mocha \"./build/tests/*.js\" --recursive --reporter spec --timeout 60000"`.

When I run `npx tsc` (to compile) and then `npm test` to run the tests, I only see :

```
C:\Users\zzyg\Programmation\workoutapp>npm test

> workoutapp@1.0.0 test
> mocha "./build/tests/*.js" --recursive --reporter spec --timeout 60000
```

But I don't get any additional information about the tests failing or passing. I don't even know if mocha actually runs my test.

Here's an example of test file I have:

```
// ./tests/standardizeString.test.ts
import assert from "assert";
import { standardizeString } from "../src/utils/standardizeString.js";

describe("standardizeString()", function () {
    it("should remove excess spaces and replace them by underscores", function (done) {
        const str: string = "hey    there";
        const result: string = standardizeString(str);
        const expected: string = "hey_there";

        assert.equal(result, expected);
        done();
    });

    it("should return a string in lowercase", function (done) {
        const str: string = "TeStInG";
        const result: string = standardizeString(str);
        const expected: string = "testing";

        assert.equal(result, expected);
        done();
    });

    it("should remove non-alphanumeric characters", function (done) {
        const str: string = "@l!p";
        const result: string = standardizeString(str);
        const expected: string = "lp";

        assert.equal(result, expected);
        done();
    });

    it("should replace accented letters by their non-accented equivalents", function (done) {
        const str: string = "crême brûlée";
        const result: string = standardizeString(str);
        const expected: string = "creme_brulee";

        assert.equal(result, expected);
        done();
    });
});
```

I wanted to run my tests using mocha. I expected it to display the details of each test (passing or failing), but it doesn't. There is no error and the only thing displayed in my cmd is:

```
C:\Users\zzyg\Programmation\workoutapp>npm test

> workoutapp@1.0.0 test
> mocha "./build/tests/*.js" --recursive --reporter spec --timeout 60000


C:\Users\zzyg\Programmation\workoutapp>
```

I am running node.js v20.2.0, Typescript v5.0.4 and Mocha v10.2.0. This what the folders look like:

[fOLDER ARCHITECTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfrOZ.png)